# Forward declaration in Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, forward-declaration

I'm trying to use Qt with C++. I'd use QT for programming in Python before.

my simple test doesn't work. This is my tour.h file:

```
#ifndef TOUR_H
#define TOUR_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QTableView>

class TourTable;

class Tour : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Tour();

/*protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);

private slots:
    void newCompetitor();
    void remCompetitor();
    void finalReport();
    void openPage();
    void savePage();
    void reloadTitle();*/

private:
    TourTable _table;

};

class QStandardItem;
class QStandardItemModel;

class TourTable : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TourTable();
/*  bool isChanged();
    QString windowName();
    void finalReport();
    void newCompetitor();
    void remCompetitor();
    bool savePage();
    void setChanged(bool value);
    void openPage();    

protected:
    void itemChanged(QStandardItem item);

private:*/
//  bool _secondBetter(p1, p2);

    Tour _parent;
//  QStandardItemModel _model;
//  bool _saved;
//  bool _changed;

};

#endif
```

I'd commented almost everything in this code to isolate the problem, but I still don't know what is causing this. Is my first trying in C++.

The error message is:

```
tour.h:28:12: error: field ‘_table’ has incomplete type ‘TourTable’
  TourTable _table;
            ^~~~~~
tour.h:7:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class TourTable’
 class TourTable;
```

Can someone help me to solve that?

Comment: Since you're declaring `TourTable` class in a same file there's no need for `forward declaration`, you can push `TourTable` before declaring `Tour` class.

Comment: This won't work since he has Tour reference in TourTable class

Comment: What you need to do is to use TourTable *_table; You will be able to construct the object later in cpp file

Comment: Unsure why qmake is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declaration in C++ allows to reference a type before its definition. Problem here is that in your code:

```
class TourTable;

class Tour : public QMainWindow
{
    // ...

    TourTable _table;

};
```

You're not only referencing the type `TourTable`, you're instantiating it with `TourTable _table;`. This requires a complete definition of `TourTable`.

A solution could be to define `TourTable` before `Tour`, as follows:

```
class TourTable : public QTableView
{
    // ...

    Tour _parent;
}

class Tour : public QMainWindow
{
    // ...

    TourTable _table;
};
```

But that just moves the problem since you're instantiating `Tour` in `TourTable`.

Depending on the complete design, the solution may be to use pointers. Something like that:

```
class TourTable;

class Tour : public QMainWindow
{
    Tour();
        // forward declaration of the constructor,
        // see below for the definition

    TourTable* _table;
        // no complete definition of TourTable at this stage,
        // only a forward declaration:
        // we can only declare a pointer
};

class TourTable : public QTableView
{
    TourTable(Tour* parent):
        QTableView(parent),
        _parent(parent)
    {
    }

    Tour* _parent;
}

Tour::Tour() // definition of Tour's constructor
{
    _table = new TourTable(this);
        // TourTable has been defined : we can instantiate it here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, this error is coming from your compiler -- not from qmake -- and is a limitation of the language. But it can be easily overcome by creating a class that defines a parent/child behavior and making any classes where you want that behavior to inherit from the base class, as Qt's [QObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) does.

Both `QMainWindow` and `QTableView` inherit from `QObject`, so if you make use of `QObject`'s parent/child system this design may be redundant. To find the parent from the child call [parent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#parent), and to find the children from the parent you can call [children()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#children).